# AppEngine: Model is not immutable

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to insert an instance of a model into an ndb database.

It keeps on giving me the "Model is not immutable" error.

I have tried with different model names, but still the same error.

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    username = ndb.StringProperty()
    email = ndb.StringProperty()
    lwr_username = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.username.lower())
    lwr_email = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.email.lower())
```

Here's my insert code:

```
entity = User()
entity.email = ""
entity.username = "bob"

logging.info(entity)

#Commit data asynchronously
entities = [entity]
futures = ndb.put_multi_async(entities)

#Build Response whilst database is committing
response = {

}

#Wait for commits to finish
ndb.Future.wait_all(entities)
```

This is the full stack trace

```
Model is not immutable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp-api/1.377037445874907069/v1/handler/userHandler.py", line 11, in post
    responseCode, response = UserService.create(locale, json.loads(self.request.body), **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp-api/1.377037445874907069/v1/service/userService.py", line 37, in create
    ndb.Future.wait_all(entities)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 345, in wait_all
    waiting_on = set(futures)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 3017, in __hash__
    raise TypeError('Model is not immutable')
TypeError: Model is not immutable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `futures` list, *not* `entities` to wait for the async process to complete:

```
ndb.Future.wait_all(futures)
```

The `wait_all()` function stores these in a `set()` object, and sets require the contents to be hashable. Since mutable objects cannot be stored in sets or dictionaries, Google engineers added an explicit `TypeError` to the `Model.__hash__` method, which is what you see raised here.